# Как использовать команды в Android?

Tags: android, runtime, su

Я хочу использовать две команда вместе в одном коде

```
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
 "su", 
 "cp /dev/graphics/fb0 /sdcard/dcim/hello", 
 });
```

Но дебагер пишет unknown id. В чём дело?

Если оставить только `"su"`, команда будет выполнена успешно.

Comment: короче вот такой вариант прокатил

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/s.png");
     
но пишет Permission Denial: can't read framebuffer pid=12844 uid=10087

Собственно говоря почему так, если командой "su" программа получает Root?

Comment: @reklamapsy, потому что эти две команды были выполнены в разных процессах и воспринимаются они как несвязные друг с другом. Нужно получить поток ввода процесса и в него ввести вторую команду(посмотрите мой ответ).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, как делаю я:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(true ? "su" : "sh");

// Поток ввода
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
// Поток вывода ошибок
StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
// Поток вывода
StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

os.writeBytes("cp /dev/graphics/fb0 /sdcard/dcim/hello");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
os.close();

process.waitFor();
```

Можно без потоков вывода, если они не нужны (StreamGobbler я использую для вывода на экран). И можно без команды **exit**, если команда сама правильно завершится.
Такой подход увидел в исходниках библиотеки [RootTools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/).